# MySQL index, using greater than and order by on different columns in query

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by

I'm trying to optimize a query that uses >= comparison on one column, and order by with a different column. Example query below:

```
SELECT table1.title FROM table1 WHERE table1.date >= '2014-01-16 22:04:16' ORDER BY table1.vote_count DESC LIMIT 10 OFFSET 0;
```

I haven't found a way to avoid using filesort; MySQL will retrieve all the rows that match the >= comparison, and then use filesort. This is problematic, because the date range can be very large and include many rows.

```
SHOW CREATE TABLE table1;
| table1 | CREATE TABLE `table1` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`title` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
`date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
`like_count` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
KEY `date` (`date`),
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=685 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 |
```

And the EXPLAIN SELECT below:

```
EXPLAIN SELECT table1.title FROM table1 WHERE table1.date >= '2014-01-16 22:04:16' ORDER BY table1.vote_count DESC LIMIT 10 OFFSET 0 \G

*************************** 1. row ***************************
id: 1
select_type: SIMPLE
table: user_playlists
type: range
possible_keys: date
key: date
key_len: 9
ref: NULL
rows: 14
Extra: Using where; Using filesort
1 row in set (0.03 sec)
```

Comment: Show what `explain select ...` says. Have you run `analyze table table1`? Also show the output of `show create table table1`

Comment: My actual table has a lot of unnecessary columns for this questions. I'll make an edit, but I believe all the pertinent information is here.

Comment: Yes, you can leave out some columns that aren't used in the query, but include all other information.

Comment: Can you do the explain with "\G" instead of ";"?

Comment: To get rid of filesort `CREATE INDEX yourIndexName ON table1(vote_count);`

Comment: Tin, if I didn't have the `WHERE table1.date >= '2014-01-16 22:04:16'` clause, then your suggestion would be the best optimization. However, the query as it is right now would not use the vote_count index you suggested, MySQL would have to do a full table scan to find rows that meet the `WHERE` clause conditions.